# Reset bundler path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

How can I reset the bundler install path to default?

I had initially set it with `bundle install --path .gems` but now I'd like to reset it to the default system location.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
bundle install --system
```

[Bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_install.html)

**Edit - this command has now been updated!**

See @Najmul's answer for the latest version

Answer (score 5):

For anyone visiting this in 2021, the above mentioned `system` flag is now deprecated.
You have to set the bundle config by running: `

```
bundle config set --local system 'true'
```

and then you run:

```
 bundle install
```

as usual.